# Kafka connector: How to perform query with OR operator and incrementing column?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using kafka connect to source data from Oracle db to Kafka topic. I want to fetch data from one table  based on increasing id or status column, like SQL statement:

`SELECT * from TABLE_X where ID > Y or STATUS = 'Z';`

Is there any possibility to combine these two `or` conditions with using `incrementing.column.name` connector property?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [query-based ingest](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/#query-based-ingest) using `query` property and combine it with `incrementing` mode.

Source: [**Kafka Connect Deep Dive – JDBC Source Connector**](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector) by [Robin Moffatt](https://www.confluent.io/blog/author/robin-moffatt)